# Passing console.log as listener for events

Tags: javascript

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/calvintennant/jBh3A/

I would like to use `console.log` as a listener for an event :

```
badButton.addEventListener('click', console.log);
```

As demonstrated in the fiddle, this will result in an error.

I understand how to circumvent the error (by wrapping `console.log` in another function). What I would like to know is *why* the error happens. Is there some security feature preventing the use of native functions being used in this way?

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your question.

Comment: which browser(s) are you testing with? I guess Chrome because I get an error in Chrome. But it works in IE9, and fails silently in Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because inside the `log` function, `this` must be the console (it's implementation dependant). If you pass it directly as event handler, `this` would be the widget as you can see by trying

```
goodButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { console.log(this);});
```

Another solution than wrapping it in a function you create is to pass `console.log.bind(console)` (but not if you want to be compatible with IE8) :

```
goodButton.addEventListener('click', console.log.bind(console));
```